# Remove margin from subnavigation menu

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hello i'm trying to remove the left and right "margin" (i don't know if it's the right word) , so all menu buttons can fit inside the bar.

[image]

I want all the menu to fit so if in the future i want to add/edit buttons i can do it.
I'm learning HTML/CSS and i kinda understand but i don't know how to remove this.
i tried previewing with chrome dev tools but it didn't help
thanks for the help i really appreciate it !

here's my code : 
HTML file (with js script for dropdown)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header_test_2.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>CFTC - TEMPLATE HEADER AND FOOTER</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <section class="navigation">
      <div class="nav-container">
        <nav>
          <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Connaitre la CFTC</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Histoire</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Valeurs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Identité</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Syndicat CFTC-FPT 34</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Organisation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Rôle et définition</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Vie Professionnelle</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Formation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Statut</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Carrière</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Temps de Travail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Congés</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Vie Pratique</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Action Logement</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Pensions Alimentaires impayées</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Prime d'activité</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Apprentissage</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#!">Activités</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Actualités</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Presse</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Adhésion</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#!">Les + adhérents</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Espace adhérents</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Nous rejoindre</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Coordonnées</a>
              <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li>Syndicat CFTC-FPT 34</li>
                <li>UD34</li>
                <li>Fédération CFTC FPT</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>
,  </header>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) { // Begin jQuery
    $(function() { // DOM ready
      // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
      $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
        $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
        // Close one dropdown when selecting another
        $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
      // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
      $('html').click(function() {
        $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
      });
      // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
      $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
        $('nav ul').slideToggle();
      });
      // Hamburger to X toggle
      $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
      });
    }); // end DOM ready
  })(jQuery); // end jQuery
</script>

</html>
```

And my CSS File

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "oswald";
 src: url("fonts\oswald.regular.ttf");
}


.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}

.brand a, .brand a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  float: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #028893;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: oswald;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: #1D71B8;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after, nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

/* Mobile navigation */
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  /* height: 70px; */
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }

  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

That's were things are needed to be changed

Comment: You have set a max-width of 1000px in in the nav-container style. This is causing the layout to only accommodate 1000px of size and the rest is acting as a padding. I hope that I'm making sense

Comment: @SudhanshuBhagwat Yup you're right, i get it thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `max-width`

```
.nav-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```